# How do I hide/show views that are layered in a "container" view inside a viewcontroller XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

The following issue only happens when testing on my physical device (iPhone 6+). It works on the simulator.

---

I have a viewcontroller with a header and a footer section which show/hide different subviews depending on the current state.

The subviews of the containers are defined within the viewcontroller XIB using AutoLayout, and are added to their respective containers on ViewDidLoad.

The problem is that after I add the subviews to the header and footer containers, I'm not able to change the "Hidden" property of the subviews to effectively display the ones I need to show/hide.

[image: xib file]

You can see this breakpoint for example, which shows that the Hidden property is coerced to the value it was assigned on ViewDidLoad, where I defaulted it to false.

[image]

I tried using ***BringSubviewsToFront***, but this also did not work. The subviews retain the *Hidden* value they had after ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace header/footer item instead changing its visibility.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Artur!

I tried removing all the Subviews of the container view and adding the one I needed every time the state changed, but ran into reference issues which sometimes crashed.

Actually, I'm now able to get the subviews to hide/show by referencing them as an index of the container view instead of by the outlet.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm now able to get the subviews to hide/show by referencing them as an index of the container view instead of by the outlet.

So by replacing:

```
defaultFooterView.Hidden = true; //an outlet to the view on the XIB
```

with (effectively):

```
containerView.Subviews[0].Hidden = true; //the defaultFooterView
```

it works.